# extract the hash key for facebook application do not work system display an error message on the CMD

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, cmd, connection

i am new to the development of facebook so i am trying to build an android application with connection with the facebook and i read the starting facebook SDK for the android development and i download the facebook SDK  and when it come to the facebook developer webiste i created the app in the **Native android app**  where   i need  the **key hash**

the problem is in the extracting of the key hash where the CMD in on windows 7 display an error message :

**'keytool' is not recognized as an internal  or external command operable  program  or batch file.**

## the command is:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

can anyone help me ?

i will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Check that the directory the `keytool` executable is in is on your `path`.

(For example, on my Windows 7 machine, it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` folder.)

Comment: @ Sunil Mishrai checked and the path of the executable keytool is C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin is their any error with this ??

Comment: you can set the it using `path` command e.g. `path "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin"`

Comment: so  what is the command that i must write it in the cmd can you give me the finale command ?

Comment: i followed the steps as it say but still give me the same error message about keytool

Comment: 1. Type `path "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin"` in cmd 2. type `keytool` to check if keytool has been added. 3. Run your command to generate fb hash

Answer (score 0):

if printing it in app isn't an issue you can run this code to display it

```
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("my.package.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md;
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("hash key", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: @ Ivo Beckers  what i need is to get the key hash before i create the app but thank you for your help